# Laravel Datatables: Link String as Id Routing Issue

Tags: laravel-5, datatables, routes

I am having an issue with my datatables returning a 404 error when I try to link a string. For my id an years I had no problem because they were ints, but the string is causing problems. I have a list of teams, if click oilers-84, i get teams/oilers-84, but it returns nothing even though I have a teams/show blade. If i leave it as 84 oilers, it returns teams/84 with the info from the 84th id in the table. Instead, I want to return the 84-oilers team page. Not sure if its a routing issue, controller, or if I need to convert the teams to a teams_id column someway. Sorry if that's a lengthy intro, I'm having a hard time understanding the issue exactly. In my web.php i simply have this: Route::resource('/teams', 'TeamsController'); Here is rest of my code:

Controller @show

```
public function show($id)
{

    $teamdatas = GameData::findOrFail($id);

    return view('teams/show', compact('teamdatas'));
}
```

datatables.blade.php-- script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#table').DataTable({

    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    order: [],      
columnDefs: [
{ "orderable": false, "targets": [10] }
   ],

    ajax: '{{ route('datatable/getdata') }}',

    columns: [
        {data: 'id', name: 'id', "fnCreatedCell": function (nTd, sData, 
 oData, iRow, iCol) {
        $(nTd).html("<a href=/games/"+oData.id+">"+oData.id+"</a>");
    }},
        {data: 'year', name: 'year', "fnCreatedCell": function (nTd, sData, 
   oData, iRow, iCol) {
        $(nTd).html("<a href=/games/showyear/"+oData.year+">"+oData.year+"</a>");
    }},

        {data: 'game', name: 'game'},

        {data: 'homeTeam', name: 'homeTeam', "fnCreatedCell": function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {
        $(nTd).html("<a href=/teams/"+oData.homeTeam+">"+oData.homeTeam+"</a>");
        }},

        {data: 'awayTeam', name: 'awayTeam'},           
        {data: 'homeWin', name: 'homeWin'},
        {data: 'awayWin', name: 'awayWin'},
        {data: 'tie', name: 'tie'},
        {data: 'stage', name: 'stage'},
        {data: 'round', name: 'round'},
        {data: 'stageSeries', name: 'stageSeries'},
        {data: 'seriesGame', name: 'seriesGame'},
        {data: 'homeScore', name: 'homeScore'},
        {data: 'awayScore', name: 'awayScore'},

    ]

});
 });
  </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: `findOrFail()` needs an (int) id

Comment: I messed around with using a $slug, and I got it to render a page, but it was blank and I couldn't seem to add content to it even if i created a "84-Oilers" blade to test it out. I will see if $slug is the answer... datatables is new to me and laravel is still fairly new to me... thanks again